# Simples clique no input ativa o evento "DOMSubtreeModified"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou a usar este código:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {            
    document.title = 'Editar Material *';
    formChanged = true;
}, false);
```

Para verificar alguma alteração nos vários formulários e imagens possíveis de editar. O problema que encontrei foi o seguinte: basta um clique sobre um `:input` para disparar o evento.

É possível ignorar o simples clique no campo de `:input` sem nenhuma alteração? Eu sei que há maneiras mais corretas para fazer verificação de alterações nos formulários, mas preciso de usar algo parecido com isto.

Comment: Tem como dar mais detalhes ou criar um mini exemplo executável? Isso que você está fazendo é um "edit in place"?

Comment: Como assim "edit in place"? Há demasiado código para eu colocar aqui, são umas mil linhas de javascript numa view razor.

Comment: JEditable:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html
Os 8 melhores plugins Edit In Place de Jquery:
http://www.omegaweb.com/8-best-edit-in-place-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Não estou a usar nada disso. Estou a usar o razor para criar os inputs e isso, depois os dados são carregados através de várias chamadas ajax, pois carrego dados de várias tabelas. Queria fazer o meu codigo um pouco melhor, mas se o utilizador não clicar em nenhum campo tem o efeito que desejava. (o código que já estava implementado mostrava o aviso SEMPRE)